# Completly silencing commands like `dd`, `:delete` of old vim versions (7.4.152)

Tags: vimscript

*Discl.* I'm perfectly aware of `:silent :delete` or `silent :normal dd`, I'm also aware of `execute()`.

My context is that I run unit tests with vimrunner on travis, with the version of Vim currently available on travis (7.4.152). vimrunner uses +clientserver feature and `:redir` to execute the commands sent to the Vim server.

Unfortunately while `:silent :delete` perfectly works when using interactively the code I'm testing, within a `:redir` I end-up with `"nn fewer lines"` that messes the test. While I could use `setline()` or `append()` to add or change lines, there is no `deleteline()` to silently remove lines.

Is there an option somewhere that I've missed, that completely silences these interactive commands?

Comment: Maybe you could give a big value to `'report'`: `set report=999`, but I think you would still get a message when you undo an edit.

Comment: @user938271. That's it. Thanks, I completely forgot about it. Also, the test I need to investigate is a snippet expansion, so there is no going back in history.